# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement and remote connection warning

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am trying to install some packages in a conda environment and i keep getting the following error. At first I thought that it had something to do with **jupyter notebook** as I had installed it recently in my base environment. So I uninstalled jupyter but I still can't install the packages I want. Any ideas on what is the problem would be very helpful.
[image]

If I try to install **keras tuner** for example with conda, I get:
[image]

Comment: did you update `pip`?

Comment: why don't you use `conda` to install packages instead of `pip`?

Comment: are u sure that u have a full access to internet ? might be blocked.

Comment: Firstly, i also cannot upgrade pip because it gives the same error. I managed to install scipy with conda and before installing I get this message "The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::keras==2.10.0=py310haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::keras-preprocessing==1.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::tensorflow==2.10.0=mkl_py310hd99672f_0
  - defaults/win-64::tensorflow-base==2.10.0=mkl_py310h6a7f48e_0
done"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keras-tuner` package (not `keras_tuner`) is only available through Conda Forge. Installing Conda Forge packages into an Anaconda **base** environment is not recommended. Instead, create a new environment and specify exactly the packages you would like to have available. E.g.,

```bash
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.10 tensorflow=2.10 keras=2.10 keras-tuner
```

Also include the `ipykernel` package if you intend to use this as a Jupyter notebook kernel.